# Not showing tabs in media overlay

Tags: media, users, routes

After upgrades of most modules on my websites, including the media 7.x-2.0-unstable4 to 7.x-2.0-unstable6, i have a problem with the tabs on the overlay media browser.

It does not show the tabs, but instead render them as normal li links.
I have attached a screenshot. It's in Danish, but i suppose you can get the idea from it.

I am not sure if it's a media module issue or something else causing it.
I've tried to clear cache and also changed java script aggregration settings without any luck.

http://www.oldtrafford.dk/media.png

Comment: URL seems to be broken (404.) Please attach images to your question directly if they are important.

Comment: Should be working. checked it from several computers. Can't attach it to the question as i lack credits in here